# How to restore http service on Windows 10 while accidentally removed the service

Tags: windows, services

While installing Apache as a service, I have accidentally removed Windows' default http service. Now many dependant services don't work and I can't get it back.

Is there a way (beside restore points since it's been a while and I noticed this too late) to fix this both as a service and in the registry?

What I have done:

1. Installed Apache using `http -k -n "http"` command.
2. Noticed that I have misspelled `httpd` and typed `http` instead.
3. Removed the service using `sc delete http`
4. Reinstalled Apache using `http -k -n "httpd"`
5. Found out spooler isn't starting.
6. Searched the web and found `http` was a Windows service required for many discovery tasks.
7. Panicked

Comment: Which service and how exactly did you remove it, and what is your Windows version.

Comment: The `http` service on Windows 10 Pro. Using `sc delete` command.

Comment: In the duplicate answer you will see how to in Programs and Features of Control Panel to uninstall and re-install the HTTP feature.

Comment: @harrymc I have seen those answers and those did not apply here. I am not looking for IIS and `WebHTTP` service. This is what I'm looking to restore: https://support.microsoft.com/am-et/help/820129/http-sys-registry-settings-for-windows

Comment: If you can't do this with that answer of using Programs and Features, you will need to do it with an [In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: @harrymc That also is not an option for me because I have heavily modified my windows; and I believe this is a professional community. I think the answer to how manually install a critical service is a plausible one. I am a C(++/#) developer and make money as a web developer. I can reinstall the driver as a service myself but since I haven't done that before I just asked for someone with more experience to guide me. It is not an everyday task, that's why it is not found easily on the net, like repairing or a feature install. Thanks.

Comment: The only advice, perhaps wrong, I can give is find the service executable file and install it as a system service. But that's all I can think of.